# DNS into other VLAN on ipv6

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, ipv6, vlan

I had this setup:

```
L3 - L2 - Client
     |
    DNS Server
```

where the L3 had SLAAC and stateless DHCPv6 enabled. There were no VLANs configured.

At this point, the Client was getting an IP and a DNS query from the server when in autoconfig mode, so all was working well.

Now, i changed the setup to this:

```
L3 - L2 - Client
  \ _ Server
```

Where the interfaces to L2 and to the server are in two different VLANs. The connectivity is working well (ping are going through from client -> server), but the client is not getting a DNS query anymore. Did i overlook something here? What do i need to configure so that the DNS requests will work from the other VLAN? I already changed the DNS servers IP in the L3 DHCPv6 config accordingly to its new VLAN IP, but that didnt help. Sorry for bad english, hope someone can help.

The server is running Windows Server 2012 R2, the Client Windows 10 Pro, the L2 switch is a Netgear GS105E, the L3 switch a cisco catalyst 3560.

Comment: What are 'the L2' and 'the L3'? Do you mean a switch and a router?

Comment: layer 2 and layer 3 switch